# Why if this API gives the "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header", can I access it through the address bar or http://www.hurl.it

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, xmlhttprequest

EDIT: See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/216605/how-do-web-servers-enforce-the-same-origin-policy for a great explanation on why browsers enforce Access-Origin restrictions but servers (like Hurl.It) are not restricted.

I'm trying to use the API found here http://forismatic.com/en/api/. But I am getting the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error. If that is the case, why can I access the API by entering the URL with its parameters directly into the address bar of my browser, or through http://www.hurl.it ? I am using codepen if that affects anything.

My code is below. Thank you very much, I've been searching around for a few hours but I'm at a dead end.

```
var quoteRequest =  new XMLHttpRequest();

quoteRequest.open("GET", "http://www.api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", true);

quoteRequest.send();

var quote = JSON.parse(quoteRequest.responseText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If that is the case, why can I access the API by entering the URL with its parameters directly into the address bar of my browser, or through http://www.hurl.it ?

Because that's how the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) works: It applies to ajax requests, not direct requests (typing it in to the address bar) or server-side requests (what Hurl-It does).

The purpose of the SOP is to prevent Page A using Page B's resources within Page A, from within the browser. This is primarily to protect the *user*, since when the browser requests resources from Page B, it may use the user's session or other credentials, revealing information to Page A's code that it should have access to. [apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710446/) has a [great explanation of this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/216607/9888) over on programmers.stackexchange.com; here's an excerpt:

> For example, suppose I accidentally load `http://evil.com/`, which sends a request for `http://mail.google.com/`. If the SOP were not in place, and I was signed into Gmail, the script at evil.com could see my inbox. If the site at evil.com wants to load mail.google.com without my cookies, it can just use a proxy server; the public contents of mail.google.com are not a secret (but the contents of mail.google.com when accessed with my cookies are a secret).

If that API doesn't grant access to your origin (your page), and doesn't offer a JSONP alternative, you can only use it indirectly, via a server in the middle (your own server, or Hurl-It, etc.).

Comment: Thank you that clears things up a bit. What exactly is Hurl It doing then? How does a server-side request work?

Comment: @irishjauntingcar: Hurl-It is doing the request from a *server*, not from a browser. A server-side request is exactly that: A request made from a server, not a browser.

Comment: @t-j-crowder I suppose what I mean is why is request from a server more secure (and therefore allowed by default) than a request by the browser? Especially if you could use another server as a middle man to use Page B's resources inside Page A?

Comment: @irishjauntingcar: It's not about security, it's about access control. If someone providing an API doesn't want to share that API's output for free, and someone else gets around it by redirecting through a server, the person providing the API can quite readily block that server's requests, as they come from a single (or small set) of servers. In contrast, if the integration is client-side, the requests can be coming from any of millions and millions of machines; you can't shut all of them out.

Comment: Cheers @t-j-crowder I understand now :)